# How to query users from on-prem only using Microsoft Cloud

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph to query users for my application. I noticed many guest users showing up in the results. These users are not in our on-prem AD that is synced.

I've tried the various OnPremisesXXX properties, but it doesn't look like they support being filtered on (via the $filter query).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I thought I had tried to filter on `OnPremisesSyncEnabled`, but maybe I did something wrong the first attempt. My filter statement looks like this:

```
onPremisesSyncEnabled eq true
```

As I learned, not all properties are usable for the filter command. I used [this documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/user.md) to help find the answer. Note: I actually ended up on the group.md page which mentioned that the property supports $filter, but the actual user.md page doesn't mention it, so this document may not be 100% up-to-date, but it did  ultimately help me find my answer.